# Mostrar valores dentro de un rango

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente código SQL:

```
SELECT (CAST(DATEDIFF(dd,Fecha_Nacimiento,GETDATE())/365.25 as int)) Edad 
FROM Clientes
```

Lo cual me devuelve la edad, lo que quiero hacer es poder visualizar en una consulta el rango de la edad, es decir, una tabla con tres columnas representando los rangos existentes. Por ejemplo: si tengo 15 registros, cinco con una edad entre 18 y 27, otros cinco con entre 28 y 37 y otros cinco con 38 y 48 años, poder visualizar la cantidad de registros entre los rangos que dije anteriormente.

¿Cómo podría hacerse?

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/101525/edit) poniendo la etiqueta del manejador de base de datos que estás usando? De ese modo podrás tener una respuesta específica y la pregunta quedaría clara para futuros usuarios con la misma duda.

Comment: Listo, gracias por el consejo :)

Comment: Podrías editar tu pregunta e incluir el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si usas un [`DATEDIFF`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) con `year` como magnitud obtienes la diferencia en años calendario

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME
SELECT  @Now = GETDATE() 

SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(year,Fecha_Nacimiento,@Now) < 18              THEN 'Menor a 18 Años',
            WHEN DATEDIFF(year,Fecha_Nacimiento,@Now) BETWEEN 18 AND 27 THEN 'de 18 a 27 Años',
            WHEN DATEDIFF(year,Fecha_Nacimiento,@Now) BETWEEN 28 AND 36 THEN 'de 28 a 37 Años',
            WHEN DATEDIFF(year,Fecha_Nacimiento,@Now) BETWEEN 28 AND 36 THEN 'de 38 a 46 Años',
            ELSE THEN 'Mayor de 46 Años'
       END
    FROM Clientes
```

**Nota:** Particularmente con [`GETDATE()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql) al ser una función no "determinística", es decir que no devuelve siempre el mismo resultado (obviamente), y al usarla varias veces en la misma consulta, prefiero trabajarla desde una variable (`@Now`) que siempre mantendrá el mismo valor.

Answer (score 1):

Si he entendido bien, podrías usar varias consultas mediante UNION, especificando en cada una el rango de edad.

Select count(*)
where edad ...

Union

Select count(*)
Where edad...

Comment: Y eso lo pusiera bajo el codigo sql que puse en la pregunta o donde?

Answer (score 0):

Una forma que se me ocurre rápidamente seria usando IF, pero de esta forma lo mostrara en filas, espero que te sirva a elaborar la solución.

```
SELECT nombre,
DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(fecha_nacimiento, '%Y-%m-%d'))/365.25 AS edad,
IF(
(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(fecha_nacimiento, '%Y-%m-%d'))/365.25)  < 27, "de 0 a 27 Años",
IF(28 < (DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(fecha_nacimiento, '%Y-%m-%d'))/365.25) < 36,"de 28 a 36 Años","Otros")) AS rangos
 FROM personas
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A por cierto es posible que esa forma de calcular la edad no sea la más precisa, me da la impresión de que una persona mayor se puede tener un margen de error de días .

Comment: Que gestor de base de datos es ese? en sql server me marca errores :/

Comment: Ese es SQLyog Community, En windows uso ese y Workbench Community, En MacOS uso SequelPro